# Crawl space plumbing nightmare

Tags: plumbing

My wife and I purchased a mountain cabin that is supported by a concrete block crawl space foundation. I noticed that there is a common 2" vent stack that rises from the 4" sewer line exiting to the septic and extends up the rear wall of the cabin, terminating just below the bathroom window. Upon examining the plumbing in the crawl space, it is a series of mismatched black plastic pipe, pvc and galvanized pipe with drainage pipe that does not have a p-trap at every fixture. The sewer line from the septic extends upward and is a Christmas tree for a maze of sewer and drain piping that makes no sense.

I plan to replace all of the supply lines with 3/4" and 1/2" copper because I'm most familiar with using it. In replacing the drain piping, the problem is that I must make all replacements from the crawl space or face tearing out newly renovated walls everywhere above. What I would like to do is extend downward from each fixture 24" max to install p-traps so that I will have room to install a 2" common vent line starting just above my drain levels beginning at the highest sink and then extend all vent lines down through the floor to eventually tie into a common 3" stack that I plan to extend upward through the roof.

My question is can the 2" common vent line that services all of the fixtures run below the house in the crawl space to join a 3" vent stack as long as each tie-in originates from above the p-trap at each fixture? It seems counter-intuitive to ultimately run the common vent downward but as I said, it would constitute a nightmare if we have to tear out all of the walls to run common venting or even provide individual vent stacks at each fixture.

Is a crawl space arrangement possible here and if so, can I install it as planned and described?

Thanks for any recommendations or guidance.

Comment: How will the water that inevitably accumulate in the vent line be dealt with ?

Comment: I wouldn't use copper unless you post a guard.

Comment: In answer to any water accumulation, I was planning to turn the terminal end of the 3" common out through the block to the exterior and use a 3" threaded cap that I can open occasionally to let it drain if necessary. Just don't know whether such an arrangement would violate code. As for needing to post a guard, 101 ABN/75 RGR REG/E CO, C CO LRRP VTNM 67-69. We have a sign posted below my old battle flag that I'm still looking for a mission if anyone wants to make it happen. So far, no takers.